# Failing to add Android Studio path to enviornment variable. (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: android-studio, environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04

I have done following steps
1.  `gedit ~/.bashrc`
2. added

```
# Add the Android Studio /bin directory to PATH
export PATH=$PATH:~/opt/android-studio/bin
```

3.`source ~/.bashrc`
Rebooted the laptop and tried to open studio.sh using

```
user@user:~$ sudo ./ studio.sh
[sudo] password for user: 
sudo: ./: command not found
user@user:~$ ./studio.sh
bash: ./studio.sh: No such file or directory
user@user:~$ studio.sh
studio.sh: command not found
user@user:~$ sh studio.sh
sh: 0: Can't open studio.sh
```

Please tell me the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `ln -sf /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh ~/.local/bin/android-studio`, then use command `android-studio` to launch?